# documents-query - how is dls:documents-query() in MarkLogic 10 different from MarkLogic 7?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7, marklogic-10

I have upgraded from ML7 to ML10 and restored the database as well, but `dls:documents-query()` returns

```
cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version")
```

on ML10 and

```
 cts:properties-query(cts:registered-query(17524193535823153377, ("unfiltered"), 1))
```

on ML7. What are the major differences? Is it something related to the permissions and roles the users are assigned?

Comment: It is probably related to changes in DLS that happened between ML7 and ML8. There are instructions telling you need to migrate DLS documents: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_65479

Comment: Thanks @grtjn for the comment. This indeed helped me solve some issues when i moved from ML7 to ML10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some really interesting details here [Known Incompatibilities with Previous Releases](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_65479).

Thanks @grtjn for the help.